# Where-clause called more often than item count

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a `List<Order>` and I'm trying to filter this using LINQ:

```
var grouped = from o in orders
  group o by o.OrderNumber into g
  select new { Id = g.Key, Orders = g };

var GroupedList = grouped.ToList();

int max = GroupedList.Count();
int count = 0;
var filtered =
    from g in GroupedList
    where IncrementProgress(max, ref count)
    select g.Id;

var filteredOrders = orders.Where(o => filtered.Contains(o.OrderNumber));
```

Inside the `IncrementProgress` I print `count` and `max` to the debug-output. `max` is in my test 3500 and I get Outputs from `count` of 150000 and counting.

**Does someone have any idea why?**

PS: In my production code there is filter logic instead of `IncrementProgress`.

**Update:**

Here the `IncrementProgress`-Method:

```
private bool IncrementProgress(int max, ref int count)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Filtering {0} of {1}", ++count, max);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you show us  `IncrementProgress`  method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because LINQ is lazy and `filtered` is not a collection - it's an in-memory query, which just stores information how to evaluate result, not the result itself. Because of that, every time you use `filtered` it's being evaluated again, iterating over `GroupedList` and checking `where` condition again.

It means, `where` condition will be evaluated `orders.Count() * GroupedList.Count()` times.

Add `ToList()` call to `filtered` to evaluate it eagerly.

```
var filtered =
    (from g in GroupedList
     where IncrementProgress(max, ref count)
     select g.Id).ToList();
```

But, because you're only using `Contains` on `filtered` later, you should use `HashSet<int>` to store results. It will make `Contains` call *O(1)* instead of *O(n)*, which should increase performance a lot.

```
var filtered =
    new HashSet<int>(from g in GroupedList
                     where IncrementProgress(max, ref count)
                     select g.Id);
```

Comment: Thanks. Works gread and much faster thanks to your additional optimization!

Answer (score 2):

Your `LINQ` query is executed every time you enumerate the filtered collection, in your case each time you call the Contains method.

Try to declare your filtered variable as `(<LINQ Query>).ToArray()`.
This will enumerate the query just once.

Sorry for poor formatting (mobile phone).
Hope it helps.